# Everything is deleted when ' *' is used in sed

Tags: linux, sed

Here is the code

```
cat > a111 << eof
0
hi MIKE
3s
#sd'3s.3 *.x'
end mike

END
eof

sed /' *'/d a111
```

Everything will be deleted in file `a111`, but if `sed /'*'/d a111` is applied, only the 4th line is deleted. What's the difference between `'*'` and `' *'` or `'2*'` in the sed command?

Comment: Where are people getting the idea to put script delimiters (`'`s) inside of scripts (`/'...'/`) instead of around scripts (`'/.../'`)? Been seeing that a lot lately and just trying to understand where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `*` matches all the lines where there's zero or more consecutive spaces, so matches all the lines (you can always find zero repetitions of any given character) and everything is deleted;
- `2*` matches all the lines where there's zero or more consecutive `2`; everything is deleted for the same reason;
- `*` is quite anomalous; normally, as in the expressions above, `*` is a quantifier, which says to match zero or more instances of the character or group that precedes it, but here it is at the beginning of the regex. If you ask me, this should be rejected as an invalid regex, but POSIX begs to differ:

  > POSIX 1003.1-2001 says that `*` stands for itself when it appears at the start of a regular expression or subexpression, but many nonGNU implementations do not support this and portable scripts should instead use `\*` in these contexts.

  (from the [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html))

  So, here `*` is matched literally, and the only line that gets deleted is the one that contains a `*`.